# JavaScript Links VS CSS Links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that HTML is read line by line. When you link multiple css files like a normalize file and a stylesheet file the stylesheet file should be linked after the normalize file because of CSS importance specificity and source order. It appears that this doesnt affect JavaScript files that are linked.  Can I link my JavaScript files in any order?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Musical Playlist</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Music Playlist</h1>
<div id="listDiv">

</div>
<script src = "js/helpers.js"></script>
<script src = "js/playlist.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They'll be executed in the order they're referenced.  Whether or not you can effectively change that order depends on whether or not they have any dependencies on each other.

Comment: As David said, it depends on dependencies. Usually in production you won't go with multiple scripts/ css links in html file because of performance. Later you will learn about tools like webpack or some other tools that help you manage your dependencies and files and minify them for production.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can swap order without issues, however like mentioned if you'd use a framework/tool/... that would need to be available for the rest of your code to run it should be included earlier.

This is also why some scripts want to included in the `<head>` of your page and not at the end of the `<body>`, otherwise they would not be availble when they are needed.

The same goes for dependencies in the JS files, let's say that I have a file `menu.js`  which I supply with a config variable from `config.js` I would have to include `config.js` before `menu.js` to prevent issues and undefined variables.

Comment: Obviously this is a very simple explanation of something that can be way more complex, do keep that in mind

Comment: I'd argue that "in most cases" the order of javascript files *does* matter.

Comment: It's a valid argument, and I see where you're coming from. I'll update the answer to reflect that since it could be misleading

Answer (score 0):

If you’re planning on using any frameworks for JavaScript, make sure it’s linked prior to your main JavaScript files. Each JavaScript link is read sequentially, so if you try to run your main JavaScript file that contains a framework function before you link the framework, it’s not gonna work.

Other than that, if your JavaScript files are simply filled with functions then it doesn’t matter what order you link them in. Unless one of your JavaScript files runs and executed when the website loads that should be run first.